# How do I draw my own submenu arrow in owner draw menus (and prevent windows from painting its arrow on top of mine)

Tags: windows, winapi, menu, submenu, ownerdrawn

Windows seems to draw the submenu arrow **after** I have done my painting in [WM_DRAWITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775923%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), how can I stop windows from drawing the arrow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Owner Drawing the Submenu Arrow](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/menu/miscellaneous/article.php/c13017/Owner-Drawing-the-Submenu-Arrow.htm) on CodeGuru.

In a nutshell, the OS always draws the arrow after you are done drawing the menu item, but you can use `ExcludeClipRect()` to exclude the menu item's rectangle from the `HDC`'s drawable area after you are done drawing inside of it, so that the OS can't draw over top of your drawing.